# "It's raining outside" - does present continuous/progressive tense have a distinct meaning?

Tags: meaning, present-continuous

Present continuous/progressive tense?

As for meaning, I guess it sets the scene but am I missing something?

Comment: I think you mean "It's raining outside". "its" is a possessive. "it's" is a contraction of "it is".

Answer (score 5):

We mostly use the present progressive for things that are happening right now. Simple present most often expresses a 'generic' sense, things that happen repeatedly or habitually throughout the present era.

> PROGRESSIVE: It's raining in Knoxville right now.
>   SIMPLE: It rains a lot here in April.

Comment: So it is present progressive? Thats good & thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The progressive tense (which can be used in the present, future or past) is generally used to stress the ongoing nature of an action.  For instance...

> It's raining right now

Stresses the ongoing nature of the rain right now.

> It was raining when I went out an hour ago

Places my going out during the time it rained and it does this by stressing the ongoing nature of the rain, which sets up the context for my going out.

To get a better idea of the second case, look at the difference in meaning between these two examples:

1. I ate dinner and the phone rang.
2. I was eating dinner and the phone rang.

(1) says the phone rang after I ate dinner, while (2) says the phone rang during dinner.  This interruption is communicated by stressing that the dinner was ongoing, which creates a "window" of time during which I place the phone ringing, all courtesy of the use of the continuous.

Another example:

1. He left when I came in.
2. He was leaving when I came in.

Although similar, (1) hints that maybe he left because I came in -- although that case is ambiguous (but isn't much of language?).  (2) implies that his leaving was independent of my coming in.  Again, by placing my arrival within the window of his leaving, the possibility of my arrival causing his leaving is eliminated.

Comment: So it is present progressive. Thank you @R. Barzell

Comment: @Touche it's not present progressive, it's just a progressive (or continuous or gerund).  The "was leaving" form is the past progressive for instance.